# laravel dompdf not rendering complex html with rowspan and colspan correctly

Tags: html, pdf, php-7, laravel-5.6, dompdf

I have a very complex dynamic table that I need to output to pdf in laravel 5.6.  The project I inherited had Dompdf installed and is already rendering all other content.  Therefore, I use it as well for compatibility.

My issue is I have a table to render consisting of 13 columns and undefined number of rows, where intermittently a column may span 13 columns for a heading or a row may span several rows at any given time or a colspan within the rowspan that spans 11 columns from the 3rd row.  No html is hardcoded except the `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<th>` and `<tbody>` tags.  The html within the `tbody` tag is dynamically generated depending on the array data.

Everything looks great in the browser and when I `view()` the pdf blade as well as ctrl + p it creates a nice pdf, although for some reason rowspan cells spanning to the next page does not carry over markup and content.  As soon as I try to `stream()` the pdf the table becomes warped and looks like a toppled building built by Picasso.

Here is links to pdf's, the one I ctrl + p lost its colour due to me removing names.
[File to view pdf printed with ctrl + p](https://ufile.io/ic578vzj) 
[Pdf streamed with Dompdf](https://ufile.io/wac4n6tb)

Image of viewing pdf in browser
[image: Pdf image rendered in browser with view]

Image of pdf when streaming via Dompdf:
[image: Warped tabled rendered to pdf with stream function]
Html sample rendered in browser:

```
<tr style="background-color: #5b8969;">
    <td rowspan="2" style="background-color: #F8C293; color: black;">Spray 4</td>
    <td>Pollinate</td>
    <td>7-10 days later</td>
    <td>BENOMYL WP 25KG </td>
    <td>benomyl 500g/kg</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>2.00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Full bloom</td>
    <td>Black Spot</td>
    <td>WETCIT DUO 20L </td>
    <td>borax 10g/orange oil 50g/l</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>25.00</td>
    <td>100.0000</td>
    <td>120.0000L</td>
    <td>2500.0000</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="13" style="background-color: #9fb5d3;" class="h3 font-weight-bold">ANOTHER ONE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="7" style="background-color: #F8C293; color: black;">Spray 7</td>
    <td>20 cm</td>
    <td>African Armyworm</td>
    <td>CERATO 250 EC 5L </td>
    <td>pyraclostrobin 250g/l</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>2.00</td>
    <td>10.0000</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>20.0000</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Can someone please help and give me a clue on how to output such a complex table with Dompdf? As I would really want to keep on using only one PDF rendering library in this project.
Otherwise I am open to suggestions to use another pdf library that can handle rowspan that span pages and this complex layout?

**Update**
Based on a comment by Don't panic (he suggested validating html and fill empty `td` tags with `&nbsp;`), that he subsequently deleted.
I re-wrote the HTML as a template into my `pdf.blade.php` view. Now, I only output the values in a loop in my view. Firstly, it becomes easier to maintain and to leave off the validation he suggested. I also filled every empty `<td>` tag with a hardcoded `'&nbsp;'`. This is to more easily see why certain rows end where they should and others not. The result is sadly still the same, a warped table. But it does seem to be a rowspan issue not colspan. The `'rowspan'` rows stack after another. So maybe missing a <s>td</s> `tr`.

**Solved rowspan stacking issue**
Two weeks of testing and only problem was it was not outputting certain rows' opening  tags, which lead to rows not knowing when to begin. *Now only problem left is rowspan across pages*.

**Update on update**
So I have really tried everything I can to get DomPdf to do what it is suppose to do, which is rendering pdf's.  I have read a bit more and found that this [library](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1388) has a long standing issue of not being able to render `rowspan` accross pages.  Therefore, on to the next rendering library `wkhtlmpdf` or I could logically divide rowspans to stop at end of page and start again on new page.  Will have to check my watch on this one.